# how to set Anonymous delegate as one parameter for InvokeSelf?

Tags: c#, html, silverlight

I tried to use InvokeSelf for silverlight to communicate with html: 
InvokeSelf can take object[] as parameter when making a call:

```
  ScriptObject Myjs;
  ScriptObject obj = Myjs.InvokeSelf(new object[] { element  }) as ScriptObject;
```

then I want make a call like with anonymous delegate:

```
Object obj;
obj = InvokeSelf(new object[] { element, delegate { OnUriLoaded(reference); } });
```

I got the error said: 
Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot assign an anonymous method to an `object`. This is because the C# compiler doesn't know what delegate type should be used. You can fix the code by creating a delegate explicitly. Since this is Silverlight you can also use more succinct lambda expression notation:

```
obj = InvokeSelf(new object[] 
  { element, new Action(() => OnUriLoaded(reference)) });
```

That said, I'm not sure if it is possible to pass a delegate to JavaScript, but you should be able to compile the code now and try that.